# Как узнать порядковый номер группы символов в регулярных выражениях PHP?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

```
INSERT INTO `students` (`id`, `id_group`, `is_captain`, `stud_num`) 
VALUES (106,21,0,''), (107,21,0,''), (108,21,0,'')...
```

, в которой нужно убрать одно поле таблицы (например "stud_num") и соответственно убрать все его значения. При чем поле может быть на любой позиции, не обязательно четвертым в конце. Т.е. код должен быть универсальным.

Возможно ли это сделать регулярными выражениями?

Есть идея как-нибудь узнать порядковый номер заданого поля, после чего удалить по этому номеру его название и все его значения. Но вот как это реализовать - идей нет. Кто с регулярными выражениями провел не одну ночь - прошу помочь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Но для конкретных позиций нужно писать конкретные шаблоны. Вот пример для указанных в вашем вопросе:

```
$str = "INSERT INTO `students` (`id`, `id_group`, `is_captain`, `stud_num`) 
VALUES (106,21,0,''), (107,21,0,''), (108,21,0,'')";

$str = preg_replace_callback('~\(.+?\)~', function ($m) {
    return preg_replace('~,\s*[^,)]+(?=\))~', '', $m[0]);
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

В результате sql-запрос будет таким:

```
INSERT INTO `students` (`id`, `id_group`, `is_captain`) VALUES (106,21,0), (107,21,0), (108,21,0)
```

---

Дописал универсальный вариант *(с возможностью указать позицию для удаления)*:

```
$str = "INSERT INTO `students` (`id`, `id_group`, `is_captain`, `stud_num`) 
VALUES (106,21,0,''), (107,21,0,''), (108,21,0,'')";

$pos = 4;

$str = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=\().+?(?=\))~', function($m)use($pos){
    $tmp = preg_split('~,\s*~', $m[0]);
    unset($tmp[--$pos]);
    return join(', ', $tmp);
}, $str);

echo $str;
```